# SQL to check if database is empty (no tables)

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to check if a database is totally empty (no tables) using an SQL query. How can this be done?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Presumably, you mean 'no user defined tables or views' since the system catalog will exist.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `table_name`) FROM `information_schema`.`columns` WHERE `table_schema` = 'your_db_name'
```

will return the actual number of tables (or views) in your DB.  If that number is 0, then there are no tables.

Comment: this will also return the number of views.

Comment: But if that number is more than 0? Maybe there are no tables, but there are views?

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Yes, but I don't believe that you can have a view without a table to base it on?

Comment: @MiffTheFox:


CREATE DATAbASE DbWithNoTablesAndOneView;
GO
USE DbWithNoTablesAndOneView;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewWihtoutUnderlyingTable
As
SELECT 1 AS n;
GO

Comment: A more realistic example:

create view wrapped_rand_view
as
select rand( ) as random_value
go
create function wrapped_rand()
returns float
as
begin
declare @f float
set @f = (select random_value from wrapped_rand_view)
return @f
end


http://www.mydatabasesupport.com/forums/sqlserver-programming/245612-generate-random-number-each-row.html

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov Well then, just use longneck's answer then.

Answer (score 14):

```
select count(*)
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
   and table_schema = 'your_database_name_here'
```

Comment: Hmm, I think there is something wrong with this SQL. I'm using MySQL and getting 0 on a database with tables in it.

Comment: It worked well for me:
But I hardly found how to call
First I wrote result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery which returns -1
Then after I found
result = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
which returns zero if there is no table.

Answer (score 7):

In MYSQL:

```
use DATABASE;
show tables;
```

Answer (score 6):

To get a list of all databases without tables in MySQL:

```
use information_schema

select schema_name from `schemata` s
  left join `tables` t on s.schema_name = t.table_schema
  where t.table_name is null
;
```

Cheers, Christian

Comment: This is absolutely the right way to go if you want to get all empty databases. Thanks @Christian!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 or greater, you can use one of the system views to acheive this for the current db:

```
select Count(*)
from sys.tables
where [type] = 'U'
```

Answer (score 2):

SQLServer implementation:

```
USE database_name
SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
```

Answer (score 0):

"select * from information_schema.tables" will give you a list of tables on most databases.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:
select Count(*) from user_tables

Answer (score 0):

I needed something that would give me an exit code to use in Bash. This builds off of @longneck's solid answer. If the database has tables, the `select` statement will set the `contents` column as "has tables". Grep will return a successful `0` in this case, otherwise it will return a non-zero.

```
#!/bin/bash
user=username
pw=passwd
db=database
mysql -u ${user} -p"${pw}" -D ${db} --execute="SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN '0' THEN 'empty database' ELSE 'has tables' END AS contents FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema = '${db}';" | grep 'has tables'
echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
db_name='my_db'
mysql -s --skip-column-names -e "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_name) FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '$db_name'"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** In order to verify your databases is not empty you can watch list of tables and measure instances in it.

**first:** perform simple connection to your db `mysql -u <userName> -p` ,run `show databases;` pick your database using  `use <databaseName>;` and then run `show tables;` and expect to have list of tables.

```
+----------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_databaseName                 |
+----------------------------------------+
| databaseA                              |
| databaseB                              |
| databaseC                              |
+----------------------------------------+
```

**Second:** Perform simple count action on primary key / main table on sql and count instances:

```
select count(*) from <primaryKeyColumn>;
```

count result should be > 0

```
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   100    |
+----------+
```