# How to to determine if a postgresql database is empty the correct way

Tags: database, postgresql

EDIT: 
The answer which turns up in the first search at stackoverflow is **potentially dangerous and wrong** for postgresql. I was bitten by it and I deleted a database which was actually filled with a lot of schemas:
[SQL to check if database is empty (no tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012870/sql-to-check-if-database-is-empty-no-tables) applies only to mysql.

Postgresql has the feature to "SET search_path TO .specified_name".
This way you can create tables in different "name spaces", which is used by people to put more than "one schema" into one physical postgresql database.

The query in the old answer checks the default namespace. If this empty, it assumes the database is empty. But there can be 20 other database schemes in other search pathes. Which is often used by users, which buy "one database", but run 10 applications in different search pathes in order to avoid additional costs.

So I open the question again. What is the correct way to check if a database is empty in postgresql? To be more specific, how to check if it a "virgin" database just created by createdb, with no access to the physical machine?

Comment: Please call it a `schema`. Calling it `database` is dangerous, and probably the cause of your previous disaster. And your answer can be found in `pg_catalog.pg_class` Note: the other answer was for mysql, which is also the probable cause of the schema<-->database confusion.

Comment: The cited answer concerns MySql and shall not apply to Postgres. The term *schema* means something different in MySQL and Postgres.

Comment: hmm, in postgresql documentation says "database", quote  "A database contains one or more named schemas, "   So basically what are you referring to. It is one "physical database" which contains "one ore more" schemas in different search_pathes. Am I wrong here? i want to check if a database if there are no schemas in it....)

Comment: @joop  select count(*) from pg_catalog.pg_class;  returns 311. Not sure what  to check here?

Comment: That linked answer is for MySQL. And it is still valid, as MySQL uses the terms "schema" and "database" interchangeably. In PostgreSQL, you will have to check for `table_catalog` of `information_schema.columns` (instead of `table_schema`). In MySQL, every row holds the same value in those columns. -- **But note**, that PostgreSQL will have entries, which is `pg_catalog` (as `table_schema`). Their databases are never truly "empty".

Comment: can somebody post a "correct query" . I really would like to accept a correct answer.

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. Do you want to detect if a database contains only empty schemas? (Or does NOT contain NON-empty schemas ? )

Comment: what would you suggest to change in the question? It should help others and not confuse them :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have commented the linked answer is about MySQL where there is no difference between "database" and "schema".

In Postgres however one instance (installation) can have several database, and each database can have several schemas.

A Postgres instance has **at least** two database that are essential for it to work: `template0` and `template1`.

Your question isn't clear if you want to check if there are no (non-default) databases or if you want to check if a specific database contains no tables.

#### Case 1 - check if no databases exist

For that you need to connect to the `template1` database (as that is the only one that you **know** is there. Then you can run this statement:

```
$ psql -X -U postgres template1
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

template1=# select count(*) from pg_database where datname not like 'template%';
 count
-------
    33
(1 row)

template1=#
```

If that returns 0, then you know that there are no additional databases in your system. Typically there is at least a one database named `postgres` - that is what the default installation does. But that database does not have to be there.

#### Case 2 - check if a specific database contains no tables

If you want to check if a specific database contains no tables, you need to connect to that database and check the tables - excluding all system tables. The easiest way is to query `pg_class` as that contains essentially everything that can create in a database with the exception of stored functions.

```
$ psql -U postgres your_database 
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select count(*)
postgres-# from pg_class c
postgres-#   join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace
postgres-# where s.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
postgres-#   and s.nspname not like 'pg_temp%'
postgres-# ;
 count
-------
   464
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

This counts the number of tables that are not "default" Postgres tables.

The above query treats a database that has many schemas but with not tables in them as empty as well. It depends on your requirements if that means "empty" or not.

You might want to also check `pg_proc` to make sure no stored function exists and possibly `pg_extension` `pg_foreign_server` and some other [system catalog tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html) as well.

---

Unrelated:

> Postgres has the feature to `SET search_path TO specified_name`. This way you can create tables in different "name spaces"

You don't need to change the search path in order to create tables in different schemas:

```
-- create two schemas
create schema one;
create schema two;

-- create a table in schema one
create table one.some_table;
-- create a table in schema two
create table two.other_table;
```

The search_path is only there so you don't need to always fully qualify the name of a table.

Comment: Thanks for the differentiaion. Case 1 did not come into my mind  :). Actually i was looking for case 2.

Comment: There may be also temporary schemas `pg_toast_temp%`.

Comment: for the unrelated. Thanks i am aware of that. I just referred to it, as it is used  by many apps out there, which do a SET at the beginning of the connection. and then work, as if nothing else existed.

Comment: Tried this as follows expecting the query to return zero rows, but I don't get that:

`db=# \d
No relations found.
db=# select count(*) from pg_class c join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace where s.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and s.nspname not like 'pg_temp%';
 count 
-------
    36
(1 row)`

This works, but is it correct?

    select * from pg_class c join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace where s.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and s.nspname not like 'pg_temp%' and s.nspname not like 'pg_toast%';

Comment: This may not work on PG 13 (and even if it did, this strategy is not likely to be forward-compatible). On PG 13.2, the count on an empty database is 76.

Answer (score 0):

This works with PG 15 and 16 (as opposed to the accepted answer which does not, returns > 0):

```
select count(s.nspname) from pg_class c 
  join pg_namespace s on s.oid = c.relnamespace 
  where s.nspname in ('public');
```

It returns 0 if there are no tables in the db.